# reset form php value back to original value php

Tags: php, jquery

how to reset value with jquery form..my input text value with php. when I edit text and I reset, then back again to the value php..I've tried with jquery reset but input text 
lost value.

```
<form>
<input type='text' id='chk' value='<?php echo $item.$i?>'/><br/>
<input type='text' value='<?php echo $item.$i?>'/><br/>
<input type='text' value='<?php echo $item.$i?>'/><br/>
<input type='reset' id='reset_button' value='reset'/>
</form>
```

when i edit input text and then i click reset.input text losing value?how to input text back to original value?
thanks..

Comment: Save your orignal values for example to hidden inputs and then load values from these inputs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could use a form reset button: `<input type='reset' value='Reset'/>`

If you don't want the button to be visible, you could hide the button and call the `click()` method to reset the form.

Example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>With button:</h2>
<form>
  <input type='text' value='Foo'/><br/>
  <input type='text' value='Bar'/><br/>
  <input type='reset' value='Reset'/>
</form>
<br/>
<br/>
<h2>Without button:</h2>
<form>
  <input type='text' id='chk' value='1'/><br/>
  <input type='text' value='Foo'/><br/>
  <input type='text' value='Bar'/><br/>
  <input type='reset' id='reset_button' style='display: none;'/>
  <input type='submit' onclick="if ($('#chk').val() == '0') $('#reset_button').click(); return false;" value='Check if 1 (reset if 0)'/>
</form>
```

Comment: @ArdyAnt Are the values of the input fields set using jQuery?

Comment: no.values derived from php <input type='text' id='chk' value='<?php echo $item.$i?>'/>

Comment: ya..I am using a loop to generate sequential values /increment values..sorry my english bad

Comment: thanks for you answer..I use library easyui and the problem is class='easyui-textbox'